# 4-bit 2's-complement Adder

Tags: verilog

I am looking to build a 4-bit 2's-complement adder that takes in two 4-bit inputs in twos complement and outputs a 5-bit signed sum. I tried to do a sign extension on the inputs, but when I simulate, I get an X. Here are all my modules plus test bench. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
module adder4bit(A,B,Ci,sum,Co);
input signed[3:0]A,B;
output signed[4:0]sum;
input Ci;
output Co;

assign A = {A[3],A};
assign B = {B[3],B};
wire w1,w2,w3;


FA a1(A[0],B[0],Ci,sum[0],w1);
FA a2(A[1],B[1],w1,sum[1],w2);
FA a3(A[2],B[2],w2,sum[2],w3);
FA a4(A[3],B[3],w3,sum[3],Co);
endmodule

module FA(A,B,Ci,Co,sum);

input A,B,Ci;
output sum,Co;

assign sum = A^B^Ci;
assign Co = (B&Ci) | (A&Ci) | (A&B);

endmodule

module FA4bitTB;

reg signed [3:0]A,B;
wire signed[4:0]sum;
reg Ci;
wire Co;
integer i;

adder4bit uut(A,B,Ci,sum,Co);

initial 
begin

A <= 0;
B <= 0;
Ci <= 0;

 $monitor("time = %2d, Ci =%1b, A=%1b, B=%1b, Co=%1b, sum=%1b", $time,Ci,B, A,Co,sum);

 for (i = 0; i < 16; i = i+1) begin  
     #10 A <= $random;  
         B <= $random;  
             Ci <= $random;  
  end  
end  
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

When I comment out the following lines, I no longer get unknown (`x`) on the outputs:

```
assign A = {A[3],A};
assign B = {B[3],B};
```

You get `x` due to contention on `A` and `B` inside the `adder4bit` module.  You should not make assignments to `input` ports within a module.